# How to generate a single file "ESM" bundle using ESBuild for Node.js?

Tags: node.js, esbuild

In order to deploy my Node.js server to the serverless platform, I need to bundle the codebase into a single file. I have following constraints:

1. The produced output should be single file.
2. The produced output should run on Node.js runtime.
3. The produced output should be ESM only.

This is my configuration:

```js
export function getESBuildConfig() {
    return {
        format: 'esm',
        sourcemap: true,
        entryPoints: [MAIN_SERVER],
        bundle: true,
        platform: 'node',
        external: [
            'pino',
            'pino-pretty',
            /* Some more externally available modules */
        ],
        outfile: COMPILED_SERVER,
        color: true,
        plugins: [],
    };
}
```

The problem is even when using `esm` as a `format`, it is still producing Common.js bundle. I also tried changing the `platform` to `neutral` but it errors on built-in node modules like `fs`, `vm`, etc.

Comment: This isn't the same, but `bun build` from bun is capable of bundling together commonjs and esm i to a single esm file `bun build infile.ts --target=bun --outfile=file.mjs`

Comment: @pfg, Exactly what I am looking but I cannot use it for Node.js runtime.

Comment: It turns out there's actually a specific --target=node option I missed

Answer (score 2):

I have been there and spend months trying to find the answer. TLDR: you can have any 2 out of 3 requests you have listed. But never all 3. At least for now.

ESM is generally ignored on NodeJS side of things, despite all the noise around it. 99% of all NodeJS projects and libraries are CJS and will stay CJS. So, every bundler claims ESM support, but ESM formatted bundles simply do not work with NodeJS if you have CJS dependencies. You can spend weeks hunting down individual import/require. So, while NodeJS fully supports ESM, you can't bundle JS code for NodeJS to run it. Unless you have 'HelloWorld' app from the bundler vendor website that bundler is 'fully tested' with.

Practical advise: stick with CJS, as ESM is really a token option for NodeJS. I hope it will change in coming years.

Comment: After many trial and errors, I have given up on ESBuild + ESM + Node. I am using latest Webpack which happily generates reasonable ESM code which works for Node.

Comment: Can you please share a webpack config that allows bundling ESMs of NodeJS application?

Comment: It took me some time to get together this, but I created a separate post explaining ESM Bundling for Node.js. Hope this helps: https://blog.webf.zone/esm-bundling-for-node-with-webpack-0bc96d66a8e5

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/). I like that it can easily provide bundles in both `CJS` & `ESM` formats.
For example, I use this basic config setup in one of my packages, [here](https://github.com/Waveshade-Studios/toastify-simply-react/blob/v2.1.0/rollup.config.js).
You can find more examples in their official docs or over the internet.

Comment: Satisfies 1 and 3.

Comment: @RiadBaghbanli Please explain, how it is not covering point #2.

Comment: I haven't tried using Rollup extensively for application bundling. It will surely handle 1 and 3 but for second constraint, it shall involve lots of constraints, especially when your dependencies are mixed CJS & ESM. But I needed to achieve this in ESBuild due to constraints outside my control.

Answer (score -1):

ESBuild may not be capable of this, but Bun is

```
// a.js
const fs = require("fs");

fs.writeFileSync("demo", "Hello, World!", "utf-8");
```

```bash
bun build a.js --target=node > result.mjs
```

```bash
node result.mjs
```

This should satisfy all three requirements

1. The produced output should be single file.

   - Yes, unless splitting is enabled
2. The produced output should run on Node.js runtime.

   - Yes
3. The produced output should be ESM only.

   - Yes, but the compatability function `createRequire` from `node:module` is used to simulate `require()` for built in modules like 'fs'.